# Jest tests - Please add 'import "reflect-metadata"' to the top of your entry point

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, tsyringe

I'm developing an application using dependency injection with `tsyringe`. That's the example of a service that receives the repository as a dependency:

```
import { injectable, inject } from 'tsyringe'

import IAuthorsRepository from '@domains/authors/interfaces/IAuthorsRepository'

@injectable()
export default class ListAuthorsService {
  constructor (
    @inject('AuthorsRepository')
    private authorsRepository: IAuthorsRepository
  ) {}
```

And the dependencies container:

```
import { container } from 'tsyringe'

import IAuthorsRepository from '@domains/authors/interfaces/IAuthorsRepository'
import AuthorsRepository from '@domains/authors/infra/typeorm/repositories/AuthorsRepository'

container.registerSingleton<IAuthorsRepository>(
  'AuthorsRepository',
  AuthorsRepository
)

export default container
```

In the tests, I don't want to use the dependencies registered on the container, but instead, to pass a mock instance via parameter.

```
let authorsRepository: AuthorsRepositoryMock
let listAuthorsService: ListAuthorsService

describe('List Authors', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    authorsRepository = new AuthorsRepositoryMock()
    listAuthorsService = new ListAuthorsService(authorsRepository)
  })
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

> tsyringe requires a reflect polyfill. Please add 'import
> "reflect-metadata"' to the top of your entry point.

What I thought was - "I may need to import the reflect-metadata package before executing the tests". So I created a `jest.setup.ts` which imports the `reflect-metadata` package. But another error occurs:

[image: Error]

The instance of the repository is somehow undefined.

I would like to run my tests in peace.

Answer (score 32):

First create in root of your project an `jest.setup.ts`.

In your `jest.config.js`, search for this line:

```
// A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
// setupFilesAfterEnv: [],
```

uncomment, and add your `jest.setup.ts` file path.

```
// A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
```

Now import the reflect-metadata in `jest.setup.ts`:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

And run tests again.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem here and refactoring the test find out that it has to import the dependencies first and then the class of service that will be tested